# Android Parcelable or Serializable or SQLlite in case of saving photos with extra information?

Tags: android, performance, sqlite, serialization, parcelable

I am implementing an Andrdoid app what is just storing images and info about them.

```
private String rootDirectory;
private String fotoname;
private Bitmap mPhoto; //this is not serializing!
private ArrayList<Tag> tags;
private File file;
private int size;
private Bitmap thumbnail;
private String extraInfo;
private Bitmap icon;
private boolean isChecked;
```

I tried serialization and it was slow. At the beginning I just saved the photos to an Android phone and it was fast to read them. Then I recognised that I need a lot of information about photos. Then I thought that I write a text file where I keep the info about the photos, but then the reading ja updating everything is quite messy in case of deleting etc. I am really beginner in mobile coding and there might be the best solution for that, could you pls tell me what is the best solution for that kind of app?

Thanks!
Sami

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because images are quite big objects, I recommend you to use Android's content provider for images. Take a look at: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/MediaStore.Images.Media.html

This solves problem with storing pictures. Additional information you can keep in your local SQL database: http://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/databases.html

That's about storing. About fast read operation you have to provide some proxy. You can implement a class with a LRUCache member for storing pictures in memory and simple map/list/whatever of objects with text data.

Comment: Thaks for commenting! I dis this in your way so I first save the photos to SD and then I insert data to SQLLite. I got only two tables, pictures and category (pictureId is FK). How should I insert these two tables, first to picture-table and then to category-table? Transaction? Now I am inserting picture and then category with pictureId. Sounds ok?